# Suddenly cannot reach certain hosts on eos

Tags: networking, dns, networkmanager, internet, endeavouros

On my home computer running arch Linux via endeavouros I suddenly cannot connect to certain websites after rebooting. I'm using networkmanager, and the sites include github.com, qwant.com and discord does not connect either.
I've ruled out dns issues as I can get the IP with nslookup, but when I attempt to ping it I get Destination Host Unreachable.
I've ruled out router issues because my phone connected to the wifi works normally.

I'm pretty sure this has to be some kind of local configuration issue but I can't seem to find anything online about this issue, and I haven't changed anything about my configure. It correlates with me installing docker recently but removing it doesn't fix the problem so I doubt that's the issue.

At this point I'm at my wits end with this problem, any help is appreciated. I also cannot access this site from my pc so I typed this out on my phone

Edit: Of course after struggling with this for hours, I find a solution within ten minutes of making this post. Somehow I had two networks named the exact same, and one works and one doesn't. Only one shows up when I call ip a so I missed that there were two somehow.

[image]

Edit 2: I rebooted and the issue is back only I only have a single connection on my GUI now and I never managed to figure out the difference between the two...

Answer (score 0):

Checking DNS is a good start.

But DNS is designed to be cached. So the first step would be to check if you have *any* network connectivity. `ip a` is a good place to start - make sure you have an IP address and that the physical connection is working (command does NOT report "NO-CARRIER").

You've only mentioned connectivity from your web browser - checking this is NOT configured to use a web proxy would be a good idea. Also verifying the issue with a different client (e.g. curl or wget) would be advisable.

Next routing: `ip route -n`. Make sure you have a default route provisioned. Check that you don't have additional dead routes.

Make sure you can reach the default gateway. Note that while `ping` is the goto-tool for testing IP networks, there was a fashion amongst cyber-security folk for disabling it in corporate networks.

All good?

You said in your question that you had issues with "certain websites" but did not say if other websites (and specifically other websites outside your LAN) were working. I've assumed that is the case.

Next check your firewall config. I'm a bit behind the curve here - for a long time that was as simple as running `iptables -L` however nowadays, the firewall could be implemented by something other than iptables in the kernel - and not all the rules translate back to the output iptables. It's still a good place to start in the absence of a better suggestion.